# can't npm install brain.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, brain.js

so i'm trying to install brain.js in my project so i can use it
to create a kind of chat app, trying to install it however gives me an error
i'v read in places you need 64 bit version of node and i'm fairly sure i have
that, i reinstalled it using nvm ( node version manager )
node -v returns v16.13.1

```
npm install brain.js
```

heres the error log it outputs:
https://pastebin.com/raw/xukfQJLY

Comment: installation with yarn add brain.js works instead.

Comment: Seems like node-gyp failed to install, make sure to have all the required dependencies for it installed as described [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-unix)